# How to optimize database query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I've round about 20-30k record in my database, after fetcing I'm performing a operation on the data to make it proper structured, But the problem is that these two processes takes time so I want to modify query through my sql  so I don't need to loop on all the fetched data.

```
$hotels = \DB::table('hotels')->select(["name","phone","lat", "lng" 
"id","plz","rating","adress","status","website"])->get();
$hotels = $hotels->map(function($elem){
        return ["id" => $elem->id,"name"=>$elem->name,"phone"=>$elem->phone,
        "address"=>$elem->adress,"rating"=>$elem->rating,"website"=>$elem->website,"status" => 
        $elem->status, "plz"=>$elem->plz,"position" => [
            "lat" => $elem->lat,
            "lng" => $elem->lng,
        ]];
    });
return response()->json(['data'=>$hotels]);
```

Above query is giving response in this way

```
0:[address: "Chausseestraße 33, 10115 Berlin, Germany"
id: 1
name: "Hotel Mitte managed by Melia"
phone: "+49 30 254646562"
plz: 10115
position: {lat: 52.5329, lng: 13.3806}]
```

Is it possible to get same array through database query without looping again and creating custom response.

Comment: That call to `map()` looks redundant to me. It's just returning data you'd get from `toArray()` if you returned Eloquent models instead of using the query builder. If there's fields you don't want to show add them to `$hidden` on the model.

Comment: Also, showing 20-30k records IS going to be slow, no matter what, and could easily exhaust the available memory.  Unless it's for a CSV report or something, you should paginate the response.

Comment: Also, if you use models, you can just pass the response from the query to `->json()` and it will be converted to JSON automatically.

Comment: actually I'm getting position that contain lat,lng and displaying it in google maps, so I don't think so pagination option will work. plus I'm making a new position object from existing record so i have to use the map.

Comment: Lat and long should work out of the box. If not you can use accessors on models to define how they are returned, or use a resource class to transform it into the right format. Refer to the docs for more details.

Comment: Also, showing 20-30k of *anything* is totally impractical. I don't see how anyone could use any web app that didn't paginate that much data, nor can I see how Google Maps would actually let you pull in that many points in one go.